# Best way to avoid iteration

Tags: f#

I have a string

`testString = "Hello [1], my name is [2]"`

And I want to replace that so it equals

`Hello Maria, my name is My.`

I have a function that takes a string and list of replacements. Then iterates through that list replacing as necessary.

```
let parse testString (replacements: list<string>) =
        let mutable result = testString

        for index = 1 to replacements.Length do
            result <- result.Replace("[" + (index).ToString() + "]", replacements.[index-1])

        result

parse testString ["Maria";"My"]
```

But since one of my main reasons for switching to F# was to avoid iteration and mutability, what would be the best way to approach this?

I've considered a Regex replace callback on the string or a iter/map on the results list (seems to be the best way to go).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple ways that you might approach the problem in more idiomatic F#:

```
let testString = "Hello [1], my name is [2]"

let parse input replacements =
    replacements
    |> List.mapi (fun i s -> i + 1, s) //Create a tuple with the index and the string
    |> List.fold (fun (result: string) (i, s) -> result.Replace($"[{i}]", s)) input //Fold iterates through the list making the replacements recursively

let parse2 input replacements =
    let rec parse2' (input:string) (replacements:string list) i =
        match replacements with
        | [] -> input //Replacements are empty so return the input
        | s :: replacements -> 
            // Take the head element off the list using pattern matching
            // Make a recursive call after performing the replacement
            parse2' (input.Replace($"[{i}]", s)) replacements (i + 1)

    parse2' input replacements 1

printfn "%s" (parse testString [ "Maria"; "My" ])
printfn "%s" (parse2 testString [ "Maria"; "My" ])
```

Note that there's nothing particularly wrong with your code and F# encourages a mixed approach to solving problems. Mutability and 'raw' iteration are no problem if you limit their scope. In this case the variable never leaves the scope of the function so it is of no concern to the rest of your program.

Comment: Big fan of the first parse function there. But you're right, F# actually has a really nice syntax just for procedural code too. I also got a regex solution working which I've posted as a separate answer, but much prefer yours.

Answer (score 1):

While awaiting Tranquility's great response, I also did figure out a way to do match evaluator and Regex by myself if that's useful to anybody.

```
let parseReplacements (matchedIndex: Match) (replacements: list<string>) =
    let indexString = matchedIndex.Groups.[1] |> string
    let index = (indexString |> int) - 1

    if index <= replacements.Length then
        replacements.[index]
    else
        "[" + indexString + "]"

let parse input (replacements: list<string>) =
    Regex.Replace(input, "\[(\d+)\]", new MatchEvaluator(fun matched -> parseReplacements matched replacements))
```